# Acessing audiofiles stored in a cocalc folder using python

Tags: python, file

I'm working on a Cocalc project and I have my coding notebook, and a folder containing audio files ("Reference Files"). I would like to enter that folder and access all the files inside this folder. I have tried:

```
with open("Reference Files") as f:
     for audiofile in f: 
         print(audiofile)
         signal, sample_rate = librosa.load(audiofile)
```

I get the error that "Reference Files" is not a directory. I am confused because the folder is in the same directory than my notebook.  How do I solve this?

Comment: Nice username :)

Comment: Show a stack trace and a printout of `dir` or `ls -al` on the folder.

Comment: haha :D thanks, you too. I don't know how to do that as cocalc is a virtual online workspace

Comment: `print(os.listdir('.'))` to get started